# Добавить несколько элементов в Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Почему когда я пытаюсь добавить **несколько** **View** в **LinearLayout**, компилятор выдает ошибку следующего содержания:

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first.

*Вроде* раньше делал подобным образом, все было ок.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);
PieChart mPieChart = new PieChart(getApplicationContext());

mPieChart.addPieSlice(new PieModel("Freetime", 15, Color.parseColor("#FE6DA8")));
mPieChart.addPieSlice(new PieModel("Freetime", 15, Color.parseColor("#FE6DA8")));
layout.addView(mPieChart);
layout.addView(mPieChart);
```

Comment: Ты пытаешься добавить в LinearLayout один и тот же объект, который после первого добавления уже имеет родителя, и второй ему не положен, поэтому система отбивается ошибкой. Добавляй два разных объекта PieChart, как показал @Андроид Андроид

Answer (score 10, accepted):

А если попробовать так

```
PieChart mPieChart = new PieChart(getApplicationContext());
mPieChart.addPieSlice(new PieModel("Freetime", 15, Color.parseColor("#FE6DA8")));
layout.addView(mPieChart);
mPieChart = new PieChart(getApplicationContext());
mPieChart.addPieSlice(new PieModel("Freetime", 15, Color.parseColor("#FE6DA8")));
layout.addView(mPieChart);
```